# Bios INT 13h ! help needed

Tags: bios

i search lot in the internet and could not find any good tutorial about Bios INT 13h! any help would be appreciated! i have simple boot loader and i want it to be able to install itself(just read sectors from floppy and write it to the hard disk!) please help!

Comment: Why is this being downvoted and closed? Seems a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked "[*Ralf Brown's Interrupt List*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html)"? and this reference resource: [*Generic BIOS Programmer's Reference*](http://www.ousob.com/ng/bios/ng1706f.php)